# Creating Elasticsearch template targeting a specific index ES 6.x

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, search, nest

All, I am using **ES(6.7)** **search templates** to support my queries from an **ASP.NET** application at work . Our DEV and QA share the same ES nodes (Total 2 nodes). We name our indices **dev-** and **qa-** to identify each index b/w **Dev** and **QA**. The search template api documentation doesn't specify an option to give an index name while creating a template here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-template.html. We have some 30 search templates in DEV. So Is my only option is to create separate templates targeting DEV and QA? I know while invoking a search template from the code(NEST), we have to specify the index name, but if I am working on an enhancement in DEV that requires an update to an existing search template, that will break the search in QA that uses the same template. Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DEV and QA were on two different clusters, you'd have to duplicate all search templates on each cluster anyway, right?

Why not simply prefixing the search templates with `dev-` and `qa-` as well since they can exist in different versions, too?

What you're saying makes perfect sense, i.e. you might be working on a new search feature on DEV and you need to make changes to the search template but only for the DEV environment and not impact the QA one... the only way to achieve this is to have a set of DEV search templates and another set of QA search templates, there's no other way around it. Search templates must be treated like just another piece of code, whether they are deployed in the same cluster or not.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Dev and QA are on the same cluster. So My only option would be to maintain two different templates b/w DEV and QA?

Comment: Of course, since they might not contain the same version of the queries... The fact that DEV and QA are in the same cluster plays no role at all... the fact remains that both DEV and QA have different lifecycles, and so do your search templates.